# Execution failed for task ':react-native-health-connect:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: react-native

I was attempting to add react-native-health-connect to our React Native app. After adding this library, I changed the minimum SDK to 26 and the compileSdkVersion to 34. Following these changes, the following error appeared:

The class is loaded from /Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b60c0c5574f97806b258b157ffbff0eb/transformed/jetified-connect-client-1.1.0-alpha06-api.jar!/androidx/health/connect/client/units/Power.class

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-health-connect:compileDebugKotlin'.

Execution failed for task ':react-native-health-connect:compileDebugKotlin'.

Comment: Any particular reason to change the min SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I changed kotlinVersion = '1.6.10' to kotlinVersion = '1.8.0', and added the @shopify/flash-list library with version 1.6.1. The application is now working fine.